# onchange and onkeypress javasrcipt PHP

Tags: javascript, php

i have one input that needs to be numerical digit and auto calculate value input..
for numerical digit (onkeypress) running well, but for auto calculate (onchange) not working :

```
echo "<td class='custGanjil300b border1'> <input type=\"text\" name=\"nilaiBobot[<?php echo [$i]; ?>]\" class=\"inputtable textCenter\" 
                                            class=\"inputtable textCenter\" onkeypress=\"return mask(this,event);\" onchange=\"hitungtotal();\"  ></td>";
```

this for showing auto calculate :`

```
 echo "<td class='custGanjil300b border1' colspan = '5'><span id=\"total\"></span></td>";
```

this javascript for onkeypress (numerical digit)

```
<script>
   function mask(textbox, e) {

  var charCode = (e.which) ? e.which : e.keyCode;
  if (charCode == 46 || charCode > 31&& (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) 
     {
        alert("Please input numeric characters only");
        return false;
     }
 else
     {
         return true;
     }
   }
 </script>
```

this for onchange for auto calculate :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function hitungtotal() {
var elems = document.getElementsByName('nilaiBobot');
var sum = 0;     
for(var i =0;i<elems.length;i++){
sum+=parseInt(elems[i].value)
}
document.getElementById('total').value  = sum;

}
```

please help me, and sorry for my bad english :(

Comment: You should not use `<?php echo [$i]; ?>` inside a PHP ECHO function.

Answer (score 0):

```
var elems = document.getElementsByName('nilaiBobot[]');
```

this line of  code cannot get elements.

Please use:

```
<input type=\"text\" name=\"nilaiBobot\" ...
```

```
var elems = document.getElementsByName('nilaiBobot');
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, i just try to change that, but still not work :(